# Maximal set of independent random variables on a discrete probability space

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, independence

Suppose we have a finite discrete probability space $(\Omega, P)$ (say $|\Omega| = n$). What is the maximum number of random variables on this space that are mutually independent?

With a bit of work we can find random variables $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ so that $\mathrm{cov}(X_i, X_j) = 0$ for $i \neq j$. It is not the case, however, that covariance $0$ implies independence.

-e- I changed the notation to be consistent with what it seems is more used.

Comment: I think of a probability space as  $(\Omega, \mathcal F, P)$.  Are you saying $|\Omega|=n$?

Comment: Assuming your $X_i$ are indicator random variables ($\Omega = \{1,2,...,n\}$, $X_i = 1_{i}$) it suffices to look at events $A = \{X_1 = \sigma_1, ..., X_n = \sigma_n\}$ for $\sigma_i \in \{0,1\}$.

Comment: @Henry, $\Omega$ is a set, $P$ is a function $P: \Omega \rightarrow [0,1]$ such that $\sum_x P(x) = 1$?. What is $\mathcal{F}$? -e- I see, $\mathcal{F}$ is $\sigma$-algebra on $\Omega$. Since I want $\Omega$ finite, may as well take $\mathcal{F}$ as the full powerset.

Comment: @1mdlrjcmed, I don't think the indicator functions for elements of $\Omega$ are independent. $\{ X_i = 1 \} = \{ i \}$, so $P(X_i = 1, X_j = 1) = P(\emptyset) = 0$.

Comment: You're right.  My apologies.

Comment: @1mdlrjcmed, not at all, thank you for noticing and contributing

Comment: I would have thought you could have $n=1$ and $\Omega=\{\omega_0\}$ and $X_i(\omega_0)=i$ so $P(X_i =i)=1$.  Then you could have as many $X_i$s as you want (even uncountably many if $i \in \mathbb R$) and they would be mutually independent.

Comment: @Henry non-trivially, its a single random variable taking a value with probability $1$. If you assume such random variable is present only once then for uniform distribution, you cannot have more than $\log_2(n)+1$ mutually independent random variables by the derivation in EDIT section of my answer. Hopefully this helps.

Comment: @Balajisb I accept my constant random variables (which by construction each take different values) are a special case, but they seem to meet the requirements of the question

Answer (score 1):

$P(X_i = r,X_j = s) = P(X_i^{-1}(r) \cap X_j^{-1}(s)) = P(X_i^{-1}(r)) \times P(X_j^{-1}(s))$

If $X_i^{-1}(r) \cap X_j^{-1}(s) = \emptyset \implies P(X_i^{-1}(r)) = 0 \ or \ P(X_j^{-1}(s))$

Hence for all $r,s$ in the range of $X_i,X_j$, we must have $X_i^{-1}(r) \cap X_j^{-1}(s) \neq \emptyset$.

So it looks like it depends on the nature of probabilities $p_1,...,p_n$.

Uniform distribution case:

Lets say $p_1 = p_2 = ... = p_n = 1/n$.

Then lets choose binary random variables, $X_1,...,X_m$. Now choose sets $A_1,...,A_m$ such that $|A_i \cap A_j|  =  n/4$ and $|A_i| = n/2$. Then define, $X_i = 1 \iff A_i \ happens$ or else $X_i = 0$. Then $X_1,...,X_m$ are pair-wise independent.

Illustration:

Lets say $n = 2^m$ and $p_i = 1/2^m$.

Let $A$ be the actual event in the original probability space. Let $A = b_1b_2...b_m$ in binary representation.

Let $X_i = 1 \iff b_i = 1$ or else $X_i = 0$

$P(X_i = 1,X_j = 1) = P(b_i = 1,b_j = 1) = 1/4 = P(X_i = 1) \times P(X_j = 1)$.

You can show that $X_1,...,X_m$ are mutually independent.

General case:

Do Huffman coding which is source coding on the symbols $1,...,n$ and it is a prefix coding technique. Let $m$ be the maximum number of bits used. Each symbol $i$ is assigned variable length bits. Fill the unassigned bits for a symbol $i$ by $*$ so that all symbols from $1,..,n$ are assigned $m$ ternary alphabet symbols.

Let $A = i$ be the original event. Do huffman coding from $i$ and get $b_1,...,b_m$.

Now define:

$X_j = 1 \iff b_j = 1$,

$X_j = -1 \iff b_j=0$,

$X_j =0 \iff b_j =*$.

I am guessing that $Y_i = ( X_j : j \in S_i)$ for some $S_1,S_2,...$ will be mutually independent. Check it !

EDIT:

Huffman coding's job is to convert $1,...n$ into binary representation with bits as independent as possible. Infact that is the job as a source coding technique. So there is a good chance it will work in lot of cases.

For uniform distribution with binary random variables, I think the only condition is $|A_i \cap A_j|/n  = |A_i|/n \times |A_j|/n$. If you want mutual independence and not just pairwise independence we have the condition $|\cap_{i \in S} A_i|/n  = \prod_{i \in S}|A_i|/n$ for all $|S| \leq m$ as both necessary and sufficient conditon. Use this condition either to come up with new independent set or an upper bound.

$$P(\cup_{i=1}^m A_i) = 1-(1-|A_1|/n) \times (1-|A_2|/n) \times ... \times (1-|A_m|/n)$$

Now wlog assuming $A_i^c \neq \emptyset$, by independence $\cap_{i=1}^m A_i^c \neq \emptyset$ , we have, $$P(\cup_{i=1}^m A_i) \leq 1-1/n$$

Hence $$1-1/n \geq 1-(1-|A_1|/n) \times (1-|A_2|/n) \times ... \times (1-|A_m|/n) \implies (1-|A_1|/n) \times (1-|A_2|/n) \times ... \times (1-|A_m|/n) \geq 1/n$$

Assumne wlog $|A_i| \geq n/2$, if not we will replace $A_i$ by $A_i^c$.
Let $$\implies 1/2^m \geq 1/n \implies n \geq 2^m$$.

Similarly if random variables are not binary but take $d$ values we have $n \geq d^m$.

A possible converse is, let $p_i= Constant \times 1/2^i$ then by uniqueness of binary representation  there is a good chance that there does not exist any non-trivial independent random variables as $n$ increases.

Comment: To summarize, if we have a uniform distribution we can find $\lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor$ random variables, essentially by interpreting a subset of our probability space as a product of coin flips. Do you think this can be modified to give an upper bound too?

Comment: I'm not sure why use Huffman coding (I am unfamiliar with it but I looked it up and with a cursory glance I don't see why it would help). I think the idea for the general case should be to write 1 to n in binary, then take $X_i$ be the value of the $i$-th bit. We can only do this for the greatest bit if $n = 2^m$, otherwise I do not think you will get independence with all the other bits.

Comment: I have responded to your comments in the answer above. See my response under EDIT: at the end of my answer. Cheers !

Comment: @MaxK I have elaborated the upper bound derivation even more in the EDIT section at the end of my answer. Please take a look and see if its useful.

Comment: @MaxK fixed some typos.

Comment: @MaxK in the edit section I have added a possible worst case probability mass function for which no  non trivial independent random variables exists.